# updating API Prometheus metrics on an Http server error

Tags: python, docker, devops, prometheus, docker-network

I work on a docker project with several containers and I wanna use python Prometheus library to monitor some metrics in the containers, expose each container's metrics on a local port inside the docker-network and collect them in another container called Prometheus_exporter.

For this purpose, I've defined several Prometheus metrics on my FastAPI and I wanna expose them on an http server with Prometheus library's "start_http_server" method.
here's my API code and how I use it:

***api.py***: in this file I've defined my API and its endpoints

```
from prometheus_client import Counter, Histogram, start_http_server
app = FastAPI()

num_q = Counter('api_num_queries','counts number of requests sent to API', ['endpoint'])
num_err = Counter('api_num_errors','counts number of errors occurred')
latency = Histogram('api_latency', 'latency calculator')

@app.get('/userdata/{uid}')
@latency.time()
@num_err.count_exceptions()
def get_user_data(uid):
    udata = redis.get(uid)

    return udata
    

@app.get('/bookdata/{bid}')
@latency.time()
@num_err.count_exceptions()
def get_book_data(bid):
    bdata = redis.get(bid)
    
    return bdata
```

***main.py***: in this file I publish my API

```
import uvicorn
from api import app
from prometheus_client import start_http_server

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, workers=10)
```

The problem is when I place `start_http_server(8000)` in **main.py** file, like this:

```
import uvicorn
from api import app
from prometheus_client import start_http_server

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_http_server(8000)
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, workers=10)
```

the metrics are exposed but **they don't update and stay at their initial zero value** while the metrics are changing in api.py.

the other way that I tried was using *`start_http`*`server(8000)` like this in **api.py**:

```
from prometheus_client import Counter, Histogram, start_http_server
app = FastAPI()

num_q = Counter('api_num_queries','counts number of requests sent to API', ['endpoint'])
num_err = Counter('api_num_errors','counts number of errors occurred')
latency = Histogram('api_latency', 'latency calculator')

@app.get('/userdata/{uid}')
@latency.time()
@num_err.count_exceptions()
def get_user_data(uid):
    udata = redis.get(uid)
    
    start_http_server(8000)
    return udata
    

@app.get('/bookdata/{bid}')
@latency.time()
@num_err.count_exceptions()
def get_book_data(bid):
    bdata = redis.get(bid)
    
    start_http_server(8000)
    return bdata
```

this works fine at the first time and metrics are exposed with their latest value, but when I send a new request i get **"Port Already in use"** error.

what should I do and how I can expose my metrics correctly?

Comment: please dont post images. Its hard to read and work with. Some people even have to use screen readers.

Comment: Please do not include code or relevant details as images. Images are hard to search for, makes copy-pasting nearly impossible and have very bad accessibility for those that have might have trouble reading.

Comment: Thank you all. I replaced the images with codes.

Comment: Drive-by answer (apologies) but curiously I read about issues with Prometheus metrics collection using Python and multi-processes recently and your question appears (!?) to be related. See [Multiprocess Mode e.g. Gunicorn](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/blob/master/README.md#multiprocess-mode-eg-gunicorn)

Comment: Thank @DazWilkin! That seems to be the answer but I can't clearly understand it. It has explained the functions needed but It doesn't say where to use them. If you guide me a bit more, I'll be greatfull!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured something out for this. It's not really a solution but It works!
The reason for this problem is that the `http_start_server()` command doesn't reset or update the info on the port automatically and It's the `prometheus_client` library's problem.

**To solve this**, you can define a new `\metrics` endpoint in your API like below and return your metrics every time a request is sent:

```
from prometheus_client import generate_latest, CollectorRegistry
metrics_reg = CollectorRegistry()
#define your metrics and specify all the metrics registrys to be metrics_reg

@app.get('/metrics')
def get_metrics():
    return generate_latest(metrics_reg)
```

**This solution works only on API modules.**